# Android Studio - красивый переход между активностями

Tags: xml, android-studio

Собственно, 2 вопроса:

1) В каком типе лучше создавать активности, чтобы можно было сделать красивый переход?

2) Как сделать этот самый переход? К примеру дефолтный переход из родительской активности в ребёнка - ребёнок наплывает на экран справа-налево. Какие ещё есть дефолтные переходы, и можно ли придумать свои?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется transition animation. Если хотите подробно и красиво, то вам сюда: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html

Если коротко, то можете начать вот с этого примера и дальше экспериметнитовать:

Файл fade_in.xml в res/anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha 
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Файл fade_out.xml там же:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" 
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

И при запуске второй активити добавить `overridePendingTransition()`:

```
startActivity(intentToSecondActivity);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Как описываются анимации в xml, описано здесь: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween

Comment: спасибо, но верно ли это? У меня при изменении значений анимация не меняется. Можно даже опустошить файлы с анимациями, а они западают куда-то в кеш и спокойно работают даже без файлов... Помогает ребилд проекта, но это слишком долго для каждой правки